# Algorithm which removes duplicates while realtime firebase pagination

Tags: java, android, algorithm

I need to make sure that my recycler has only unique items. Just because in pagination im getting items in small portions before adding new data i need to check if there are any items which already been added to the recycler. I have created filter method but for some reason its not working.

My logic is that I have a list in my class which takes all data with first query but when second query done before add data in adapter i need to check if there are any items which already been added before and remove them from the list.

Here is the code

```
public void addRealUsers(List<OnlineUser> onlineUsers) {
    //Here we are getting small portions of new data
    mUserList.addAll(onlineUsers);
    //Third list which contains only items from new data which are not been received before
    filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
    removeDuplicates(onlineUsers);
    //Adding only filtered list items
    mAdapter.addUsers(filteredList);
}

private void removeDuplicates(List<OnlineUser> onlineUsers) {
    for (OnlineUser databaseUser : onlineUsers){
        for (OnlineUser localUser : mUserList) {
            //Checking if new received data already been added to the local list
            if (localUser.hashCode() == databaseUser.hashCode()) {
                filteredList.add(databaseUser);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Model class

```
public class OnlineUser {
    private String uid, name, image, gender, country;
    private long rating;

    public OnlineUser() {
    }

    public OnlineUser(String uid, String name, String image, String gender, String country, long rating) {
        this.uid = uid;
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.country = country;
        this.rating = rating;
    }
```

Comment: what is you model for recyclerView (the data that you pass to recyclerView)?

Comment: @EliasFazel i have added model class please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to remove duplicated items from data.

```
Set<String> stringHashSet = new LinkedHashSet<>(allDataArrayList);
allDataArrayList.clear();
allDataArrayList.addAll(stringHashSet);
```

There can be other solutions depends on how you populate recyclerView from Firebase (Realtime Or Firestore Database) So if you need more help then add your firebase query process, too.

Comment: Thank you for an answer. Do I understand right that solution based on that LinkedHashSet has only unique items? But does it the same with objects ?

Comment: Yes. Just test it. also paste the process of data retrieving from database.